# NestJS "cannot find module" error when importing classes from npm package

Tags: types, nestjs, npm-package

I have a monorepo with NestJS, NextJS and a npm package with class definitions.

This is the folder structure:

```
/rr-admin
   /rr-admin-frontend
   /rr-admin-backend
   /rr-admin-models
```

I've created this npm package to define the classes that are being used in both the front- and backend.

This is the content of `index.d.ts` within the package folder:

```
export class StudentRequest {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  status: "Active" | "Finished" | "Stopped";
  group: number;
}

export class StudentResponse extends StudentRequest {
  id: number;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

This is the content of the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@rr-admin/models",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
}
```

I've installed the `@rr-admin/models` package in the NestJS project and it can be found in /node_modules.

I import the classes like this: `import { StudentRequest } from "@rr-admin/models";`

The NestJS terminal gives the error: Cannot find module '@rr-admin/models'

When changing `class` to `type` or `interface` I don't get the error, but then I cannot use 'class-validator', because 'class-validator' only works on classes.

When I change a class in the npm package so that it doesn't match the db type, the terminal gives an error that they don't match. So in some way the file does get read.

How can I import the classes from a self-created npm package into the NestJS project?

Comment: Does `@rr-admin/models` not have a `files` or `main` field? Just `types`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes, its only purpose is to contain the types for the frontend and backend

Comment: But if you're importing it as a class for the sake of validation, then it's not "just types" as those classes need to exist at runtime

Comment: Yes you're right, they have to be classes to do the validation, not types. The problem is that I can't import them from the package as classes.

Comment: Why not? Once the `main` is fixed that should be doable, right?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I don't understand what your suggestion to solve the issue is

Comment: You say you cannot import the classes from the package, I'm asking "why not?". Once the `package.json` has a `main` you should be able to import the classes just fine